# Sharing a class between Node.js and the browser

Tags: node.js

If i have a class, what is the best way to share that class and use it in both the browser as well as Node.js?

For example a game that uses a 2D Vector math class on both the client-side and the node.js.

Comment: Do you have an example of this, a problem i've struggled with is exporting the class within node.js

Comment: use the feature detection trick. If `module` & `module.exports` exist then write to that. If `window` exists then write your class to window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[NowJS](http://nowjs.com/) is a pretty elegant way to share variables and functions between client JS and Node JS through an automatically sync'ed shared namespace.

There's also [dnode](https://github.com/substack/dnode), which the author comments on in response to a posting about NowJS here: http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2316079

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears that support for nowjs has been abandoned. There are some alternatives available, though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14097623/is-it-possible-to-share-data-between-the-client-and-the-server-using-node-js

Answer (score 2):

Also, [Haxe](https://haxe.org/), a language that lets you write using the same language for the browser and the server.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [NowJS](http://nowjs.com/), which should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Write it as CommonJS/Node.js module, so it works normally in Node.js, and then pack written module for browser using [Webmake](https://github.com/medikoo/modules-webmake). It's simplest way to share same codebase on both sides