# How do I share javascript on the server as well the client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Lot of the time I end up repeating the code on the server as well as the client. Example I have a registration form; validations I do for required field, email address regex are same on the both server and the client. I ideally want to write code in one place and not repeat.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sharing a class between Node.js and the browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750359/sharing-a-class-between-node-js-and-the-browser)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [express.js](http://expressjs.com/), take a look at the [express-expose](http://github.com/visionmedia/express-expose) module. It seems to do what you're looking for:

> expose objects, functions, modules and more to client-side js

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that you aren't talking about a node.js application (for that take a look at either now.js or express-expose).

In these cases, what I would recommend is to do as much server side as possible, as a client can disable javascript (the is a particularly strong point when dealing with validation). You could use ajax to hit up the server, run the code there, and return in javascript.