# Is it possible to share data between the client and the server using node.js?

Tags: node.js

Is there any way to share data (including objects) between the client and the server in node.js? I used to rely on a module called now.js that was designed for this purpose, but [the project has been discontinued](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4667826), and I'm trying to find a replacement. Is there any other way to seamlessly synchronize variables between the client and the server, now that now.js has been abandoned?

Comment: The now.js project looked very promising, and I hope that another module will replace it (now that support for the project has ended).

Comment: There is a module called node-object-sync that is intended to allow objects to be synchronized seamlessly between multiple clients, but I'm not sure if it would be usable as a complete replacement for now.js.


  [1]: https://github.com/jonashuckestein/node-object-sync

Comment: Share.js also looks like a good alternative to now.js.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After now.js, the two closest contenders are shareJS and dnode:

http://sharejs.org/

https://github.com/substack/dnode

Comment: I'm trying to find a good "Hello World" example for sharejs. Have you found any, by any chance?

Comment: Have you seen the notepad example? It may help: https://github.com/josephg/ShareJS/blob/master/examples/pad/pad.html

Comment: Where is the server file for this example? I haven't found it yet.